# Jquery returned 'undefined'(s) when try to get the ID of the 'select' tag through class

Tags: html, jquery

I'm trying to check if my select box is empty or not by using class. However, based on the code below, the alert returned not only the id but also another 2 'undefined'. Anyone who can tell me why is this happening?

```
<script>
   $('.test-input').each(function () {
       var el = [];
       if ($(this).val() === "") {
           var target = $(this).attr('id');
           alert(target); *// return media_type | underfined | underfined*
           el.push(target);
       }
   })

</script>

<div class="form-group col-sm-4">
    <label class="">Type:</label>
    <select class="form-control required-input test-input" id="media_type" placeholder="Choose a media">
         <option value="">Select a state</option>
         <option value="cat">Cat</option>
         <option value="dog">Dog</option>
         <option value="lizard">Lizard</option>
         <option value="snake">snake</option>
     </select>
</div>
```

Comment: What does `$('.test-input').length` return? Sure sounds like that class exists on multiple elements and some don't have an id

Comment: "underfined"? you sure? spelling?

Comment: @charlietfl The length is returned 3 in this case, but I'm sure I just write the class name one time in the select box.

Comment: @wazz Yes I'm sure it says 'underfined'

Comment: Ok. But maybe check one more time.

Comment: That length isn't lying to you, there are 3 elements with that class in page. Are you inserting new rows and copying elements with that class in doing so?

Comment: Just now I come back to my code and try to run it again, then suddenly the code works perfectly fine. But @charlietfl I'm sure I only have two select box with the same class name since I already try to find all classes with the same name and I did not add new row for this case. I'm not sure why but the code suddenly come back to normal. Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

`$('.test-input').each(function ()` will iterate through each element in your HTML that has the "test-input" class name, so when there you are cycling through those and getting an undefined from pulling its id via `var target = $(this).attr('id');`, what this means is that somewhere else in the file you must have two other classes named "test-input" without an ID.

I would `console.log("Iteration");` in the loop and check your console to see how many times the loop is being run and go from there.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. This problem that I mentioned is just occurred in the select box. I tried in the input box it works well. Based on my problem, the $('.test-input').length returned 3 regardless of the numbers of options inside the select box.